# How to get latest id in many to many field django

Tags: python, django, django-models

```py
class Recept(models.Model):
    naslov = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    sestavine = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    priprava = models.TextField()
    datum = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    avtor = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    likes = models.ManyToManyField(User, related_name="blog_recept")

    def last_like(self):

        return self.likes.latest('id')
```

So I want to return latest id of field likes but this code returns latest id of Users how can I get the latest id of likes?

Comment: You can define an intermediate `Like` model using `through` that represents each of the likes created when a user likes a `Recept`. Then access that intermediate model to find the latest objects there as outlined in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2007307/9374673).

Comment: Im sory for bothering but I looked up the answer and Im not sure what to do.I have tried something but it didnt work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As [@Mihai Chelaru](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66533809/how-to-get-latest-id-in-many-to-many-field-django#comment117618962_66533809) notes you need to filter on the through model. But there is no need to make the through model yourself, you can use the default generated one:

```
through_instance = Recept.likes.through.objects.latest('id')
latest_like_user = through_instance.user
latest_like_recept = through_instance.recept
```

Now `latest_like_user` contains the latest like's User and `latest_like_recept` contains the latest like's Recept.

Comment: Had no idea you could access the through model using the ORM without defining it like that. Learned something new today, thanks!